# Does PHP include toupper and tolower functions?

Tags: php, string

Does PHP include any function like `toupper` and `tolower`?

I want a `tolower` function which will convert `ABC` to `abc` or `Abc` to `abc`.

Similarly, `toupper` should convert `abc` to `ABC` or `Abc` to `ABC`.

Comment: What's the point in this question? -1

Comment: I'm amazed that you spent the time writing this instead of putting 'php toupper' in Google...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Comment: fwiw, this question ranks 3rd for "php toupper" in google, so it may not be as pointless as you think, it WILL help other people

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo strtolower('HELLO');
echo strtoupper('hello');
```

Answer (score 14):

[strtolower()](http://php.net/strtolower) and [strtoupper()](http://php.net/strtoupper)

Answer (score 9):

[`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/strtoupper) and [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

Answer (score 5):

```
echo strtolower('TEXT'); //text
echo strtoupper('text'); //TEXT
echo ucwords('text text'); //Text Text
echo ucfirst('text text'); //Text text
echo lcfirst('TEXT TEXT'); //tEXT TEXT
```