# Array is in UPPERCASE. Need to check both UPPERCASE and lowercase

Tags: php, arrays

Here is array

```
$country_codes_with_euro_currency = array( 'AT', 'BE', 'CY', 'DE', 'EE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PT', 'SI', 'SK' );
```

For example `$result = 'at';`

Then

```
if ( in_array(trim($result), $country_codes_with_euro_currency) ) {
echo $currency_code = 'EUR';
}
```

Output would be nothing. Need `$result = 'AT';`

So want to check both UPPERCASE and lowercase, but do not want manually to rewrite the array in lowercase.

Created such code

```
 $country_codes_with_euro_currency = array_merge( $country_codes_with_euro_currency, (array_map('strtolower', $country_codes_with_euro_currency)) );
```

Is there any better (shorter) solution?

... regarding marked as duplicate only want to inform that I do not ask how to convert UPPERCASE to lowercase. In my code there is already used `strtolower`. I show my way how I get result. And ask **for better way how to get the same result**

**Final solution**

Actually for this case one simple solution.

Leave `$country_codes_with_euro_currency` as it is (UPPERCASE).

And simply `$result = strtoupper(trim($result));`.

And then `if ( in_array(trim($result), $country_codes_with_euro_currency) )`

**And** please, where here [Does PHP include toupper and tolower functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486723/does-php-include-toupper-and-tolower-functions) is such answer (marked as duplicate)? I can not find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `strtoupper` and `strtolower` like

```
if ( in_array(strtoupper(trim($result)), $country_codes_with_euro_currency)) {
    echo $currency_code = 'EUR';
}
```

If you want to check for the lower cases then you can put `OR` with condition

```
in_array(strtolower(trim($result)), $country_codes_with_euro_currency)
```

So it should be like

```
if ( in_array(strtoupper(trim($result)), $country_codes_with_euro_currency) ||
     in_array(strtolower(trim($result)), $country_codes_with_euro_currency)) { 
       echo $currency_code = 'EUR'; 
}
```

And as **JimL** said you can do change both result and array in either upper or lower like

```
$converted_array = array_map("strtoupper", $country_codes_with_euro_currency);
if ( in_array(strtoupper(trim($result)),$converted_array) ) 
{ 
    echo $currency_code = 'EUR'; 
}
```